# how to extend the plugin?

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-cms

please help to fix the error

in django cms added plugin polls. then try to extend it for this [tutorial](https://github.com/divio/django-cms-tutorial/blob/master/Step%203%20-%20CMS%20Plugins.md). as a result of my directory structure looks [like](http://hostingkartinok.com/show-image.php?id=dddc8a21d1d025e0ac430fe678cb23ef).

The problem is that when you try to run the site console displays the following error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 85, in run
    self.result = application(self.environ, self.start_response)
  File "/home/kalinins/.virtualenvs/blogik4/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/handlers.py", line 67, in __call__
    return self.application(environ, start_response)
  File "/home/kalinins/.virtualenvs/blogik4/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 187, in __call__
    self.load_middleware()
  File "/home/kalinins/.virtualenvs/blogik4/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 47, in load_middleware
    mw_instance = mw_class()
  File "/home/kalinins/.virtualenvs/blogik4/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/middleware/locale.py", line 24, in __init__
    for url_pattern in get_resolver(None).url_patterns:
  File "/home/kalinins/.virtualenvs/blogik4/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py", line 365, in url_patterns
    patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
  File "/home/kalinins/.virtualenvs/blogik4/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py", line 360, in urlconf_module
    self._urlconf_module = import_module(self.urlconf_name)
  File "/home/kalinins/.virtualenvs/blogik4/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/importlib.py", line 40, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/home/kalinins/.virtualenvs/blogik4/blogik4/blogik4/urls.py", line 8, in <module>
    admin.autodiscover()
  File "/home/kalinins/.virtualenvs/blogik4/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/__init__.py", line 29, in autodiscover
    import_module('%s.admin' % app)
  File "/home/kalinins/.virtualenvs/blogik4/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/importlib.py", line 40, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/home/kalinins/.virtualenvs/blogik4/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cms/admin/__init__.py", line 11, in <module>
    plugin_pool.plugin_pool.discover_plugins()
  File "/home/kalinins/.virtualenvs/blogik4/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cms/plugin_pool.py", line 36, in discover_plugins
    load('cms_plugins')
  File "/home/kalinins/.virtualenvs/blogik4/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cms/utils/django_load.py", line 56, in load
    get_module(app, modname, verbose, failfast)
  File "/home/kalinins/.virtualenvs/blogik4/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cms/utils/django_load.py", line 40, in get_module
    module = import_module(module_name)
  File "/home/kalinins/.virtualenvs/blogik4/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/importlib.py", line 40, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/home/kalinins/.virtualenvs/blogik4/blogik4/djangocms_polls/cms_plugins.py", line 17, in <module>
    plugin_pool.register_plugin(CMSPollPlugin)  # register the plugin
  File "/home/kalinins/.virtualenvs/blogik4/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cms/plugin_pool.py", line 87, in register_plugin
    % (plugin, template)
ImproperlyConfigured: CMS Plugins must define a render template (<class 'djangocms_polls.cms_plugins.CMSPollPlugin'>) that exists: djangocms_polls/poll_plugin.html
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to create an html template in your template folder

in this case the template `poll_plugin.html` inside your registered template folder `djangocms_polls`

```
...
render_template = "djangocms_polls/poll_plugin.html"
..
```

this template MUST exist so that the CMS PLugin can work, this is the template which the plugin renders the context data to.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define list of templates in your settings, in [CMS_TEMPLATES](http://django-cms.readthedocs.org/en/latest/basic_reference/configuration.html#cms-templates) variable.

And... put your existing template to `djangocms_polls` subdir, so it will be in `djangocms_polls/templates/djangocms_polls/poll_plugin.html`.